# Firebase rule to only allow deletion of old data by any authenticated user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The question is about the ships branch expanded below. Everywhere only authenticated users are allowed to write their **OWN** data everywhere. However, there is one exception. **ANY** authenticated user may **read** data out of the ships branch.

So far I had no trouble but here is one special rule:

*ANY authenticated user may delete a child under any uid in the ships branch provided that the timestamp is 10 seconds or older.*

I want any user to be able to call:

```
firebase.database().ref('/ships/gp3tJa3tgThukt39EejqJpZq12L2/granit').remove();

uid: gp3tJa3tgThukt39EejqJpZq12L2

shipid: granit
```

And be granted the rights to delete only.

In order to check the age of the record I store a `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in the `perf` array at index `0` *(I am using an array here because this record is frequently updated and I want to keep data to a minimum)*.

On the client side, the program can see when a record is likely to have expired and only then call remove. This in order to avoid wasteful failed calls.

I need some help to define the correct rule. The line in question is highlighted in the second example where I attempted to define this rule.

```
{
    "ships": {
        "EnBawzb0CjZVgAKrMZD4HE3k5rW2": {
            "oasisoftheseas": {
                "param": {
                    "scale": 0.33075936163570846,
                    "type": "cruise/royalcaribbean/oasisoftheseas"
                },
                "perf": {
                    "0": 1,
                    "1": 1.11014724E7,
                    "2": 1.70473256E7,
                    "3": 115.7,
                    "timeStamp": 1475144447302
                }
            }
        },
        "gp3tJa3tgThukt39EejqJpZq12L2": {
            "granit": {
                "param": {
                    "scale": 0.12235531736978282,
                    "type": "riverbarge/granit"
                },
                "perf": {
                    "0": 5,
                    "1": 2.05622392E7,
                    "2": 13154087,
                    "3": 285.9,
                    "timeStamp": 1475144450086
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below the rules. It is the write rule for $shipid that I am interested in defining correctly.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "anchors": {
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    },
    "completed": {
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },    
    "ships": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$uid":{
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
        "$shipid":{
          ".write": "((auth !== null) && 
                      (now - data.child('perf').child('timeStamp').val() >= 10000))"
        }
      }
    },
    "shipslog": {
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. Same for the rules.

Comment: Hi Frank. I replaced the images with JSON data. I updated the rule and I think I have it working now. Still I would really appreciate your feedback. I imagine since there is no middle tier that this kind of thing happens all the time. I absolutely love firebase by the way. Just started using it and spend most of my days learning.

Comment: Hey Paul. I copied your rules into a test database and the simulator allows the delete operation (which I simulate by writing `null` to `/ships/gp3tJa3tgThukt39EejqJpZq12L2/granit`). Isn't that what you're trying?

Comment: Yeah brilliant. If you see nothing wrong with it then I am going to use it. I guess I answered my own question in the end. I have a few more questions but I will try hard and figure it out first before I bother you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out as confirmed by Frank. The solution edited in the question is correct, secure and working.

```
"ships": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$uid":{
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
        "$shipid":{
          ".write": "((auth !== null) && 
                      (now - data.child('perf').child('timeStamp').val() >= 10000))"
        }
      }
    },...
```

Any data can be written to the ships branch by the owner of the record. At a deeper level I use the uid wildcard and shipid wildcard to get to the data that can expire and needs to be removed.

The timestamp is secure as it is provided by the server on the server side. Deleting a ship can only happen by any authenticated user AND provided the difference between now and the timestamp is greater then 10000 milliseconds.

This is probably a nice clean generic way to let client apps cleanup old data without the need for serverside business logic.